A variation of the Van der Monde determinant.
I have the following polynomial with $N$ variables
$p(x_1,...,x_N) = \prod_{i=2}^{N} \left((i-1) x_{i} - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j\right)^{i-1}=(x_2-x_1)(2 x_3-x_2-x_1)^2...\left((N-1)x_N-x_{N-1}-...-x_1\right)^{N-1} $.
Let's suppose I perform the following operation $\sum_{k_1,...,k_N} \varepsilon^{k_1...k_N} p(x_{k_1},...,x_{k_N})$ with $\varepsilon^{k_1...k_N}$ the Levi-Civita tensor. I conjecture that it gives something proportional to a Van der Monde determinant, but I can't find a good proof. How can I try to prove it?
